# rxjs convert array to Observable array for parallel execution (using forkJoin)?

Tags: rxjs

How do I convert array to `Observable` array so I can run each observable in parallel using `forkJoin`? Do I write my own map function and create a new observable array or is there any `rxjs` util function to do that?

Comment: Try using [`from` operator](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/from)

Comment: `from` would just make it Observable which holds an array. What I'm looking for is: e.g. ['current', 'savings', 'investment'] => convert to [observable, observable, observable]

Comment: If you just want to create an array that contains observables do `array.map(v => getObservable(v))`

Comment: no, you have confused `of` and `from` operators, second will do what you want

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of turning an array of numbers into an array of `timer` observables and then running them all concurrently with `forkJoin`. No special RxJS util functions required. Basic Javascript `Array#map` works just fine.

```
const arrayOfVal = [1000, 1200, 800, 50, 5000];

const arrayOfObs = arrayOfVal.map((tick, index) => 
  timer(tick).pipe(
   tap(_ => console.log(index + " fired!"))
  )
);

forkJoin(arrayOfObs).subscribe(console.log); // output: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

or condensed without the `tap` operator

```
forkJoin([1000, 1200, 800, 50, 5000].map(v => timer(v))).subscribe(console.log)
```